# ngFor printing more than it should

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am getting some data from the database and displaying it with ngFor loop.

HTML:

```
<div 
  style="background:black; color:aliceblue;" 
  class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center"
  [routerLink]="['todo']">
    <h3
    *ngFor="let todo of todos"
    >{{todo.todoHeadline}}</h3>
</div>
```

TS:

```
todos: Todo[];
constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.todoService.getTodos()
    .subscribe(
      (todos: Todo[]) => {
        this.todos = todos;
      }
    );
}
```

And the service responsible for getting the data:

```
getTodos() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/todo')
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const todos = response.json().obj;
            let transformedTodos: Todo[] = [];
            for (let todo of todos) {
                transformedTodos.push(new Todo(
                    todo.todoHeadline,
                    todo.todoDescription
                ));
            }
            this.todos = transformedTodos;
            return transformedTodos;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

So I have 8 todos in the database with properties headline and description. Now ngFor prints 8 times h3 and within h3 it prints 8 times more so it displays todoHeadline 64 times. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thats a weird behavior, considering that the h3 tag contains nothing other than the interpolated expresion. Do you get any errors/warning in console?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo No errors or warnings

Comment: Can you please add the response of your HTTP request + some more info about your local environment (ng -v in case that you are using angular-cli)

Comment: I found an error, it was my mistake I put accidentally same ngFor on the wrapping div

Comment: lol, next time add the complete template to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would try to refactor this service to a more functional way:

```
getTodos() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/todo')
  .map( response => response.json().obj)
  .map( todos => todos.map(todo => new Todo(todo.todoHeadline, todo.todoDescription)));
}
```

this will make your code more easy to read and to figure outwhere the problem is.

Comment: Tnx for advice, I am still learning, I'm gonna mark this as a solution.